# How to check frequency of MSP430 clock?

Tags: microcontroller, clock, msp430, clock-speed, self-test

I'm working on a project in which an MSP430 is used to provide the timing for some stuff where accurate timing is important (it can be off by 10%, but not by 2x).  This is driven by the timer A0 running from the SMCLK clock source in this case.  I would like a self-test function by which I can check that the MSP430 clock is not *too* far from spec (it is supposed to be 25MHz).  In particular, I am concerned about failure modes (even though unlikely) that drop the MSP430 high speed clock down to a really low value (kHz) even though the chip keeps running: that would be catastrophic as far as the rest of the hardware is concerned.  There is a 32kHz clock from a crystal on this board.

(1) Is there a library function (msp430ware, etc) for checking that the clocks are ok?

(2) Can I use the 32kHz clock to check the high speed clock?  What is the best way of doing that?

(3) What clock integrity features are there on the MSP430?

Thanks!

Comment: Some MSP430s have a FLL to derive a faster clock from an external crystal. Which chip?

Comment: @CL.: It's MSP320F53xx.  There is an FLL, not sure how to use it?

Answer (score 2):

> (2) Can I use the 32kHz clock to check the high speed clock? What is the best way of doing that?

Use two timers: One on the 32kHz, one on the high speed clock. Compare the difference and check that it is in valid rage.

Answer (score 2):

(2) Use two timers, one from each clock source, and count how many ticks of the high-speed clock happen between two 32 kHz ticks. If the value is out of range, adjust the DCO appropriately.

On chips with the UCS module, the FLL can do this automatically without needing additional resources like timers. You can configure the FLL with the driverlib function `UCS_clockSignalInit(UCS_FLLREF,...)`.

(1),(3) The internal clock sources (VLO, REFO, DCO, or whatever your chip has) cannot really fail. Their only problem is that they might not be very accurate.

The external clock sources are monitored, and have error bits and interrupts. If an external crystal fails, you have to handle this somehow. (The UCS automatically switches to an internal clock source if a crystal fails, but you have to device whether this is appropriate in your application. In your case, if the 32 kHz crystal is replaced with REFO, the clock is still withing the 10% bounds.)